# How to use MultiSelect in react like all item was selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<FormControl className="uk-margin-small-top uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small-left" >
    <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-checkbox">Согласующие согласно матрице:</InputLabel>
    <MuiSelect
        multiple
        value={selectResponsibles}
        onChange={this.chooseResponsibles}
        input={<Input id="select-multiple-checkbox" />}
        renderValue={selected => (
            <div>
                {selected.map(value => (
                    <Chip key={value} label={value}  />
                ))}
            </div>
        )}
    >
        {persons.map(person => (
            <MenuItem key={person.value} value={person.label} >
                <Checkbox checked={selectResponsibles.indexOf(person.label) > -1} />
                <ListItemText primary={`${person.label} - ${person.responsibleRole}`} />
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
    </MuiSelect>
</FormControl>
```

How i need to do, from the start all items was selected? and if he want he can remove someone from them?

Answer (score 0):

What items are selected is set by the "value" prop on the MuiSelect component. In a multiple select each option has an associated value, with the value of the select component being an array of these associated values indicating what is currently selected. Hence if you want all items to be selected by default you will just need to initialise the "selectResponsibles" variable to be an array of all the items selection values. You can use a simple array map to generate this.

```
persons.map(person => person.label)
```